# SmtpClient .send() error: "message rejected as spam by content filtering"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Here is the code i wrote to send email,

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

try
{
    m.From = new MailAddress(Sender);
    m.To.Add(new MailAddress(Receiver));
    m.Subject = Subject;
    m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    m.Body = Body;

    sc.Send(m);
}
catch (Exception ex) { _Exceptions.ManageExceptions(ex); }
```

And the config file settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="xxx@xxx.com">
            <network host="192.168.0.170" userName="setsdom01\user1" password="xxx" port="25" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

It executes when i run it from my machine, i try on different PC and it is giving me the following message: ...**message rejected as spam by content filtering**..

What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the message is marked as spam because it is send from an other domain than the first messages? Maybe should look at the Content Filtering component.

Comment: Does `Sender` differ from the `from` address in the config file?

Comment: @Joey I don't think they differ.

Comment: does it have something to do with the issue?

Comment: Yeah, this might be causing the spam filter to think it's spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `NetworkCredential` backend code.

```
var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("xxx@", "xxxx");
sc.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
```

This might work

Also look this [How to Enable and Configure the Spam Confidence Level Thresholds](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995995%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) may be helpful

Comment: I am providing those credentials via my config file.